# What is the bss section of an image?

Tags: windows, operating-system, executable

I am trying to understand PE file formats and there are many sections. What is the bss section? Is that fluid and data written to that section can be overwritten anytime? Is that a storage location in memory of the loaded binary?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=%22PE+format%22+bss

Answer (score 1):

In assembler, the bss section was used to define memory space that didn't need to be initialized to any particular value. I imagine it hasn't changed.